# Python 3X evaluation behavior of dictionary get() method

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I recently had following code in mind and wondered what was wrong with it. Previously I used the .get method of dictionaries with success, but now i wanted to pass arguments too and this is where i noticed a somewhat weird behavior:

```
def string_encoder(nmstr):
    return nmstr.encode('UTF-8')

def int_adder(nr_int):
    return int(nr_int) + int(nr_int)

def selector(fun, val):
    return {'str_en': string_encoder(val), 
            'nr_add': int_adder(val)}.get(fun, string_encoder(val))
selector('str_en', 'Test') -> ValueError
selector('str_en', 1) -> AttributeError
```

The above code will never run.
To inspect the issue i supplied a small piece of code:

```
def p1(pstr):
    print('p1: ', pstr)
    return pstr

def p2(pstr):
    print('p2: ', pstr)
    return pstr

def selector_2(fun, val):
    return {'p1': p1(val), 
            'p2': p2(val)}.get(fun, p2(val))
selector_2('p1', 'Test')
Out[]: p1:  Test
       p2:  Test
       p2:  Test
       'Test'
```

I would expect the following .get('p1', 'test') to output 'p1: test' test. 
But as it appears to me, every argument is evaluated, even if it is not selected. So my question is: Why is every argument evaluated with the .get method, or how can this behavior be explained?

Comment: That's how _all_ functions work. Arguments are always evaluated before being passed to the function. `get` is not special in that respect.

Comment: yes, now i somehow see the somehow dumb question. as the dict value is a function call which will always be called by the get function...duh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict` creation is eager, as is argument evaluation. So before `get` even runs, you've called `string_encoder` twice, and `int_adder` once (and since the behaviors are largely orthogonal, you'll get an error for anything but a numeric `str` like `"123"`).

You need to avoid calling the function until you know which one to call (and ideally, only call that function once).

The simplest solution is to have the `dict` and `get` call contain the functions themselves, rather than the result of calling them; you'll end up with whichever function wins, and you can then call that function. For example:

```
def selector(fun, val):
    # Removed (val) from all mentions of functions
    return {'str_en': string_encoder, 
            'nr_add': int_adder}.get(fun, string_encoder)(val) # <- But used it to call resulting function
```

Given `string_encoder` is your default, you could remove `'str_en'` handling entirely to simplify to:

```
    return {'nr_add': int_adder}.get(fun, string_encoder)(val)
```

which leads to the realization that you're not really getting anything out of the `dict`. `dict`s have cheap lookup, but you're rebuilding the `dict` every call, so you didn't save a thing. Given that you really only have two behaviors:

1. Call `int_adder` if `fun` is `'nr_add'`
2. Otherwise, call `string_encoder`

the correct solution is just an `if` check which is *more* efficient, and easier to read:

```
def selector(fun, val):
    if fun == 'nr_add':
        return int_adder(val)
    return string_encoder(val)

    # Or if you love one-liners:
    return int_adder(val) if fun == 'nr_add' else string_encoder(val)
```

If your real code has a lot of entries in the `dict`, not just two, one of which is unnecessary, then you *can* use a `dict` for performance, but build it once at global scope and reference it in the function so you're not rebuilding it every call (which loses all performance benefits of `dict`), e.g.:

```
# Built only once at global scope
_selector_lookup_table = {
    'str_en': string_encoder, 
    'nr_add': int_adder,
    'foo': some_other_func,
    ...
    'baz': yet_another_func,
    }

def selector(fun, val):
    # Reused in function for each call
    return _selector_lookup_table.get(fun, default_func)(val)
```

Comment: "If your real code has a lot of entries in the dict, not just two, one of which is unnecessary, then you can use a dict for performance" -> yes this is my application scenario. As I wanted to make a "select" like operator. Thank you for hinting at the performance issue which arises by always creating a dictionary by calling the selector function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid evaluation of functions and only *chooses* the function, do this instead for your second block (the syntax will also work for your first block):

```
def selector_2(fun, val):
    return {'p1': p1, 
            'p2': p2}.get(fun)(val)
```